# how to build video playlist having youtube videos?

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube, html5-video, video.js

how to build a video-playlist that supports you-tube embedded videos?

i don't want page to be refreshed, just video changes dynamically if user clicks on another video,take a look at [this](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/video.php?subjectId=108106068) for your reference.

Does any of jplayer/video-js/flowplayer etc support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using video.js and the [YouTube](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) plugin you can update the source using the video.js [API](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md). You do need to specify the `video/youtube` type.

```
videojs("myPlayer").src({ type: "video/youtube", src: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mister_ben/g7mrs/

Comment: video doesn't get loaded,i looked in console to find "Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match." error.
I think your solution should work

Answer (score 0):

This is a JS trick. If you have a console to the browser (or firebug), you can see, it goes a JSON get request and response from the browser to the server and reverse. The server read out from the database, the correct embedded video, it sends to the browser, and that insert into the page DOM.

Comment: is it possible to do without db?
like get urls from some other file or a list that is hidden by css?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to dynamically change youtube src:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.4/video-js.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls
    width="640" height="264"
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
    >
</video>


<button id="change">change video</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.4/video.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/637a2916c2c4fd2b5fc55dafa3df923a92fec6d0/src/Youtube.js"></script>
<script>

    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // An example of playing with the Video.js javascript API
            // Will start the video and then switch the source 3 seconds latter
            // You can look at the doc there: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/api.html
            videojs('vid1').ready(function () {
                var myPlayer = this;
                myPlayer.src({type: 'video/youtube', src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6Sxv-sUYtM'});

                $("#change").on('click', function () {
                    myPlayer.src({type: 'video/youtube', src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09R8_2nJtjg'});
                });
            });

        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or see the discussion here: https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/339#issuecomment-164592838